# React Native Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-navigation/core' with react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have this basic React Native Code which fails to compile as soon as I import anything from `react-native-router-flux`. It throws **Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-navigation/core'**

If I uncomment line `import { Router, Scene } from "react-native-router-flux";`, everything works fine. I also manually did `npm install @react-navigation/core` but to no avail

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Scene } from "react-native-router-flux";

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}

export default Index;
```

What could I be missing?

**Versions**

React v17.0.2

react-native-router-flux v4.3.1

React-native v0.66.3

Comment: Did you try npm i @react-navigation/core ?

Comment: yes. and it doesnt help. The file already exists in node_modules folder. It is only after I import react-native-router-flux, it fails to find the path @XplosiVe06

Comment: Which version of react-native are you using? And which version for react-native-router-flux?

Comment: What is your React-native version?

Comment: @XplosiVe06, my bad. It is React-native v0.66.3

Comment: No worries, but the package has not been updated for 8 months, so I guess there are problems between your version of react-native or react-navigation, which is too recent for this package.

Try to use another package or downgrade react-native and react-navigation... which is not a really adequate solution

Comment: Absolutely right. I should have checked this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest react-native version (v0.66.3) is incompatible with react-native-router-flux (v4.3.1) which is pretty old. Its better to look for `@react-navigation/native`

Thanks @XplosiVe06 for pointing out